# DataSourceResult items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I have a problem. I need to select some `ID-s` from a `DataSourceResult` and I keep getting errors, or I can't select them.

```
DataSourceResult result = publicationClientList.ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

[image]

I need to select the `ids` from the items of `result`. Can you please help me how to achieve that? I tried in many ways, but I could not succeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your PublicationClientListViewModel, but I am guessing there is a property ID in the root of the class. You can do:

```
var ids = result.Data.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I have a property Id in PublicationClientListViewModel, but if I'm using your solution I get the following error; IEnumerable does not contain a definition for Select and the best extension method overload "Queryable.Extension.Select"... requires a receiver of type IQueryable

Comment: Did you add a directive to System.Linq ?

Comment: Yes, I have the System.Linq in my usings

Comment: Can you get the ids from the publicationClientList instead of publicationClientList.ToDataSourceResult ? I am reading your code and I believe it is possible.

publicationClientList.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

Comment: I managed to get the ids this way: I converted the result.Data to List<PublicationClientListViewModel>.var clientList = result.Data as List<PublicationClientListViewModel>;
                if (clientList != null && clientList.Count > 0)
                {
                    var ids = clientList.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();. thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for that! I knew my problem was that the structure of the underlying data was unknown and I needed to cast it some how. This was that little nudge in the right direction.